# Filtering backbone collection with multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Mates, I have a guests collection. Each guest has an inDate, an outDate and the id_beds for the bed that is occuping.
I'm trying to filter all guests fulfill the following statements at the same time:

- id_beds == bed
- outDate <== date
- inDate >== date

  ```
  App.Collections.Guests = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'guests/',
  model: App.Models.Guest,
  getBooking: function(bed, date){
  var gf = _.filter(this.models, function(model){
      // Get all Guests with id_beds = bed
          // && outDate < date && inDate <= date
  });

  console.log(gf);
  return gf;
  }
  });
  ```

Now, the thing is, that I don't know how to filter out the collection with those 3 statements.
First, don't know how to compare dates, since they're strings and can't see wich is greater than the other one.
And second, don't know how would be the logic to filter with more than 1 parameter.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Which string format are your dates in?

Comment: I'm using this format: YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Since your dates are `YYYY-MM-DD` simple string comparison works and your filter function should just return `true` when the three conditions are met:

```
getBooking: function(bed, date) {
  var gf = this.models.filter(function(model) {
    return (
      model.get('outDate') > date &&
      model.get('inDate') <= date &&
      model.get('id_beds') === bed
    )
  })
  // ...
  return gf
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is simple solution for filtering collection using backbone

First in your collection you should have a filtered function Like

```
 App.Collections.Guests = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
  filtered : function ( ) {
```

I suggest to use UnderScore filter which will return true for valid and false for invalid where true is what you are looking for. use this.models to get the current collection models use model.get( '' ) to get the element you want to check for

```
var results = _.filter( this.models, function ( model ) {           
        if ( model.get('id_beds') == bed 
           && model.get('outDate') < date
           && model.get('inDate ') < date ) 
        return true ; 
        return false ;
    });
```

Then use underscore map your results and transform it to JSON like

```
results = _.map( results, function( model ) { return model.toJSON()  } );
```

Finally returning a new backbone collection with only results

```
return new Backbone.Collection( results ) ;
```

Optionally if you don't want to keep all the data in the collection but just the filterd one you should reset the collection and skip the above return like

```
this.reset( results ) ;
```